# replacing textarea in comment box with editable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Comment box works well with `<textarea>` but I need to use `div` in place of it.
here is text area code:

```
<textarea class="commentMark" id="commentMark-<?php  echo $row['p_id'];?>" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'Write a comment'" onfocus="if (this.value=='Write a comment') this.value = ''" onKeyPress="return SubmitComment(this,event)" wrap="hard" name="commentMark" style=" background-color:#fff; overflow: hidden;" cols="60">Write a comment</textarea>
```

I tried to replace it with `contenteditable` div

```
<div class="commentMark" id="commentMark-<?php  echo $row['p_id'];?>" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'Write a comment'" onfocus="if (this.value=='Write a comment') this.value = ''" onKeyPress="return SubmitComment(this,event)" wrap="hard" name="commentMark" style=" background-color:#fff; overflow: hidden;" cols="60">Write a comment</div>
```

But in text area when I press enter comment get posted. While in div when I enter it does not make any effect.

also div appears with clicking on the "comment"  button

Comment: why not just use a `textarea`? You can create a new line when the enter key is pressed and avoid the form being submitted - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671688/preventing-enter-from-submitting-form-but-allow-it-on-textarea-fields-jquery

Comment: Please use native javascript or jQuery to attach event handlers. Over use of `onclick` `onkeypress` etc makes me a sad panda.

Comment: @martincarlin87: I have issue with textare. Using `div` I can give `Read more` option in the text. But in textarea I could not

Comment: what does the read more part do? Generally speaking, you should be able to achieve what you want with a textarea and if desired, style it not to look like one.

Comment: @martincarlin87: Yes you are right. When textarea has content more the  specific size then it only few line should appear. When user click on `view more` then only entire content should appear. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270535/adding-readmore-option-in-textarea

Comment: Ah, I understand better now, having the different elements makes it a lot tricker than if it was just one body of text rather than an `h2` and normal text. You could try something like http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable ?

Comment: @martincarlin87: I could not understand how it can be helpful to me! :(

Comment: hmm, I thought it might have been helpful, basically when initialised on your div, it would make it editable for you so that you didn't have to worry about converting from textarea to div yourself.