# Adding readmore option in textarea

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create `readmore` option in Textarea.

Here I can do it with div, but when I replace div with textarea, it just shows entire content in textarea without `reamore` option.

```
<body>
  <div class="container">  
    <h1>Demo</h1>
    <section id="demo">    
        <div>      
             <art>
            <div>
        <h2>Artisanal Narwahls</h2>
        <p>Salvia portland leggings banh mi fanny pack mixtape, authentic bushwick wes anderson intelligentsia artisan typewriter high life they sold out mixtape high life. Marfa ethnic wayfarers brooklyn keytar mixtape. Blue bottle shoreditch gluten-free, mixtape hoodie whatever pinterest viral twee fashion axe high life irony biodiesel tofu.</p>
        </div>    

         </art>
        </div>        
    </section>
  </div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="readmore.js"></script>
<script>
  $('#info').readmore({
    moreLink: '<a href="#">More examples and options</a>',
    maxHeight: 190,
    afterToggle: function(trigger, element, more) {
      if(! more) { // The "Close" link was clicked
        $('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: element.offset().top }, {duration: 100 } );
      }
    }
  });

    $('art').readmore({maxHeight: 240});
  </script>

</body>
```

Here is my fiddle. : http://jsfiddle.net/VSscB/

But in fiddle it does not give readmore option though same code and script as in my page.

Comment: There's no textarea in that code. You've also failed to provide the code for `readmore.js`. Show us the code that causes you a problem, not part of the code that works.

Comment: It sounds like you are (a) Trying to abuse a textarea as a display element instead of an input element and (b) Trying to add child elements to the textarea. The first is a terrible idea, the second is impossible.

Comment: @Quentin: Yes, because it was not working with textarea so I saw with div. Now check http://jsfiddle.net/VSscB/4/

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined ` — Include the JS files needed to show the problem in your example code.

Comment: @Quentin: http://jsfiddle.net/VSscB/7/

Comment: You're adding your `readmore` method to jQuery **after** you try to call it!

Comment: @Quentin: can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Programming_crazy — Step 1: Try to call `readmore`. Step 2: Define `readmore`. Since it doesn't exist in step 1, how could it work?

Comment: @Programming_crazy check my answer... i have explained why your code doesnt work.. and about the textarea...

Comment: @Quentin well explained..

Comment: @Quentin: readmore is in `javascript file` and I have linked it.

Comment: @Programming_crazy — Not in jsfiddle.net/VSscB/7

Answer (score 0):

you haven't loaded jQuery in jsFiddle.. you can select jQuery from "Framework and extensions" drop down menu.. and  you're code works fine... [working link](http://jsfiddle.net/VSscB/3/)
also..

(function($) {...} })(jQuery);

should be before..

```
$('#info').readmore({...});
```

because unlike your markup you posted in your question.. the readmore plugin is loaded after the $('#info').readmore({}); function in jsFiddle.. so you will get an error.. check your console..

although.. you cant' use textarea..  if you just want to edit the content... you can set the contenteditable attribute to true... inspecting. the readmore.js plugin.. i found this can be done by...

```
 $('.readmore-js-section').attr("contenteditable","true") ;
```

[updated link](http://jsfiddle.net/VSscB/6/)

Comment: @thanks: but my main problem is to use `Textarea` in place of `div` in that example. If you cab help me!

Comment: thanks. I already tried with  `<div contenteditable>` but it has issue. Like enter giving newline rather posting comment. Because I am implementing above for comment box.

Comment: then bind the keydown event to the div.. check this out... http://jsfiddle.net/VSscB/8/

Comment: thanks, what you say; can I create same thing for text area? facebook uses text area and still it has give readmore option!

Comment: facebook.. i don't remeber the last time i used facebook.. but i don't think it has "Read more" option in comment box.. there is "Read More" in already posted comments.. but in the text area.. i'm not sure.. what are you trying to acheive by the way?? o__O