# how give enter button space in javascript validation

Tags: javascript, html

I need a validation that contain enter space.

```
var addname = /^[0-9a-zA-Z\.,'";:& ]+$/;  
if(!(adres.value.match(addname))) {
   document.getElementById("ad").innerHTML="Feild Ruquired! only characters A-Z,0-9, a-z,and ',.;&:' are  acceptable";
   chk="false";
}
```

I use this code and it's working but when I press the enter button and write something in textarea field I get this error:

```
Feild Ruquired! only characters A-Z,0-9, a-z,and ',.;&:' are  acceptable
```

so I enter and write more description in a textarea field, like

```
1-somethong
2-something etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an allowance for new lines in your regular expression
A carriage return uses the invisible characters \r and a line break is \r\n.

So we just change your expression to:

```
var addname = /^[0-9a-zA-Z\.,'";:&\r\n ]+$/i;
```

And it should catch them fine. ( i added the i at the end to make it case insensitive as well.)

you can test and play with it [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/LZf7H/2976/).

Hop this helps.

Comment: Thnx for your reply..
but how alllow a enter space in regular expression

Comment: If you can post some sample text to compare against, I can show you how to adjust the expression to allow it.

Comment: var compdiscrip = /^[A-Za-z\.,-_"';&: ]+$/;

this exprssion is worked but i press enter button ans write some discripion in textarea the experssion is run and feild is requied is show ... i want i write something after press a enter

Comment: Oh... so the form is trying to submit when you press enter instead of adding a return into the text field? Here is a tread about that issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671688/preventing-enter-from-submitting-form-but-allow-it-on-textarea-fields-jquery

Comment: Thnx,, but i think u not understand i want to say..... i say i have cantact form and there us textarea name of message.... when i write in it simple it wirte and worked fine... but i hit enter key and write something again in textarea filed and press submit it not submit , and textarea feild show error message feild is required...

Comment: i want when i hit enter key and write something ,,,and submit it easily submit what thing i used in regular expression ,,that is work for that

Comment: I updated the answer. Should solve your problem now.